# Git Pull after modifying files. How to avoid conflicts?

Tags: git, github

I use Git as a solo developer. I've recently started to push my projects to private repo's online. When I create a new server I clone the repo and run any install scripts I've created to get it up and running.

The install scripts usually make changes to certain directories. For example the `cache` directory needs to have permissions to allow files to be written to it. Sometimes I also modify a config file (although I've started putting config stuff in environment variables), or pull in some content images that were not a part of the project.

When I make a change to these files I can no longer use `git pull` to only pull files that have changed. Git complains if I do a `git pull` because of conflicts.

I'm trying to find an approach that will allow me to push from local to remote, and pull from remote git (private github) to my server.

Is it possible?

Comment: Well I'd suggest keeping those changes outside the repo, but if you really can't do that a stash > pull > pop would generally work if your local changes don't have any actual conflicts.

Answer (score 8):

do `git stash` , then all your local changes will be kept aside and then you will be able to do `git pull`.
now you have fetched all remote changes on your machine.
then do `git stash apply` to reapply your configuration changes.

Answer (score 1):

Having permanently unindexed/uncommitted config changes in your local repositories is not a good way to go about this (as you are finding out).

To solve the problem at the root:

- Have one config file per environment. This can (and, unless it contains passwords or other secrets, *should* ) live inside the repository (in this case, bundle them up in a `/config` directory with separate names), or can stay outside (then you'll only have some kind of default config file in the repository which is not actually "executed").
- When you run your scripts, point them at the correct config file. You can do this, for example, by establishing an environment variable with the config file name, or by having a symlink in a common location (like `/etc/opt/...`) or inside your repository as an ignored symlink like `config/localhost`). Whatever you do, your code will know which actual file to pick.

Then you can always commit all your changes everywhere, and the config files from different environments will not be treated as one (due to different file names); no conflicts etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
git stash
```

Git stash put your changes on Stash state. Then you do:

```
git pull
```

Which pull the new changes then:

```
git stash apply
```

Will bring your changes back. Anyway you need a mergetool. I personally use and recommend PHPStorm MergeTool which I found really easy to use and have a great UI.

Answer (score 0):

Never `git pull` rather `git fetch` then decide if you want to merge or rebase on top of remote. This way you always commit your changes to local repo to keep them safe.

Way of working for what you describe I would go with local branch per server.
I would push to remote only changes that you need.

So on server you would have branches `proj-local` and `proj-remote-local` and `project-remote` (also to keep config files with passwords out of remote repository to keep them safe on current server). You work on your server `proj-local` and if you have changes that you want to publish to all servers cherry pick them and apply on top of `proj-remote-local` which then you push to `project-remote`.

Other thing is to look into `git ignore` for things you want to keep locally which will make git to not care about changes in those things and you wil work only on things you care about.